# How is this circuit working? This is Flashing LED oscillator, I guess.

Tags: transistors, resistors, oscillator, semiconductors

[image]

this is the video from where I got the idea to make it --
https://youtu.be/1c-fMErO2E4
When one LED turns on, other turns off. Then the other one turns on. This proces is repeated. Now, I'm not sure how this oscillator circuit is even working. Please help me. I have to write its working in my practical copy. Help.

Comment: [Simulate it](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html). Go to Circuits > Transistors > Multivibrators > Astable vibrator. Sometimes simulating things and seeing how it behaves just clicks in your head.

Comment: It would make more sense if the LEDs had current limiting resistors (depending on, of course, the applied voltage and LED type.) As it is, it would seem to create very high pulse currents in simple red LEDs -- especially towards the higher voltage rail magnitudes. And I'd also worry about Vbe breakdown.

Comment: we are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: When you simulate the circuit, note that DC analysis may find an unstable operating point, and transient analysis won't leave the 'symmetric manifold' unless you (or the simulator) adds some perturbation. Cute demonstration here http://www.falstad.com/circuit/e-multivib-a.html.

Comment: If the parts are too well balanced, this circuit will not start on its own, and the LED's do need series resistors. Read Harry Svensson's comment.

Comment: @jsotola I'm sorry. I just needed a little guidance on how it works. My teacher won't help me and my father couldn't understand it. If u could explain its working it would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Astable Multivibrator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator)

> A multivibrator is an electronic circuit used to implement a variety of simple two-state devices such as relaxation oscillators, timers and flip-flops. It consists of two amplifying devices cross-coupled by resistors or capacitors. The first multivibrator circuit, the astable multivibrator oscillator, was invented by Henri Abraham and Eugene Bloch during World War I. They called their circuit a "multivibrator" because its output waveform was rich in harmonics.

Comment: I never realized they were both honored Physicists who both died in WWII concentration camps.